# How to replace elements in arraylist contains elements as string of type stringbuilder

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, stringbuilder

I want to check whether I can replace elements from **ArrayList** which contains elements as Stringbuilder

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class IterationDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList< StringBuilder> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add(new StringBuilder("shruti"));
        arrayList.add(new StringBuilder("shri"));
        arrayList.add(new StringBuilder("samadhan"));
        arrayList.add(new StringBuilder("suruti"));
        arrayList.add(new StringBuilder("shreyas"));
        for(StringBuilder  str:arrayList){
            str.append("-->kharge");
        Collections.replaceAll(arrayList, "shreyas",new StringBuilder("prajyot"));
            System.out.println(str);

        }     
}}
```

Here I want to replace elements with name **shreyas** by **Prajyot**
So How to do that??

Comment: Why are you using `StringBuilder` instead of `String` for these?

Comment: I want to modify string

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use a `StringBuilder` here. Change them to `String` objects and updating them becomes quite simple:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add("shruti");
    arrayList.add("shri");
    arrayList.add("samadhan");
    arrayList.add("suruti");
    arrayList.add("shreyas");

    for (String str :
        arrayList) {
        str = str.replaceAll("shreyas", "prajyot");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach doesn't work because you pass in a `String` as a first argument and your list contains `StringBuilder`s, so the method will never find a match.

The first idea might be to pass in a `StringBuilder` like so:

```
Collections.replaceAll(arrayList, new StringBuilder("shreyas"),new StringBuilder("prajyot"));
```

But `StringBuilder` doesn't override `equals` so it uses the `Object` implementation which is equivalent to reference-equality (`==`) so it won't find a match either.

Therefore you'd have to loop through the list, find and manipulate the element manually. 
One of many ways to implement that is:

```
for (buffer : arrayList) {
    if (buffer.toString.equals(""shreyas") {
         buffer.delete(0, buffer.length() -1)
         buffer.append("prajyot");
    }
}
```

Note that this version doesn't replace the `StringBuilder` but changes it. For replacing it you'd have to iterate using the array index or use `Streams`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.replaceAll(arrayList, "shreyas",new StringBuilder("prajyot"));
            System.out.println(str);
```

As jens said, Here you are not really referencing to the original StringBuilder Object of 'shreyas'. you've provided the **new** String Object to the replaceAll method.
I'd suggest you to do this instead,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList< StringBuilder> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        new StringBuilder("shreyas");
        arrayList.add(new StringBuilder("shruti"));
        arrayList.add(new StringBuilder("shri"));
        arrayList.add(new StringBuilder("samadhan"));
        arrayList.add(new StringBuilder("suruti"));
        arrayList.add(new StringBuilder("shreyas"));
        Optional<StringBuilder> strToBeReplaced = arrayList.stream().filter(s -> s.toString().equals("shreyas")).findFirst();
        Collections.replaceAll(arrayList,strToBeReplaced.get(),new StringBuilder("Prajyot"));
        arrayList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```